# Windows encoding changed when redirecting output

Tags: python, windows

Hi I have the following python file 'test.py':

```
import sys
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8') 
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

when I run

```
py test.py
```

I get:

```
utf-8
utf-8
```

but when I run

```
py test.py > test.txt
```

or

```
py test.py | Out-File -FilePath test.txt -Encoding ASCII
```

I get from test.txt:

```
cp1252
utf-8
```

And when I run:

```
import sys, locale
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

I get:

```
utf-8
cp1252
```

---

Question:
May I know why this happen and what should I do so that the default encoding is utf-8 when redirecting?
Thanks

Comment: my understanding is that the redirection operator uses the system default char set. are you running this in a powershell.exe console or a cmd.exe console? i _think_ they both do the same thing since they use the same host ...

Comment: @Kallzvx - what does this have to do with powershell? it looks like you are running in something other than a powershell console ... `import sys` gives me lots of red error text when i try to run that in either the ISE or the powershell.exe console.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I used the `>` operator in powershell which caused the problem, so I thought they are related

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I am using Windows Powershell version 5.1

Comment: @wjandrea I get utf-8 for redirecting and not redirecting

Comment: @Kallzvx - argh! [*blush*] you are correct that it concerns powershell. ///// instead of using the redirection operator - which is known to have the earlier-mentioned problems with encoding - try using one of the to-file cmdlets that has an `-Encoding` parameter. take a look at `Get-Help Set-Content -Parameter Encoding` or `Get-Help Out-File -Parameter Encoding`. you also may need to pay attention to the BOM [byte order mark] that PoSh adds to many text files. search SO for `Powershell BOM` for more info on that.

Comment: The easiest solution is to run a command that uses redirection to pipes or files via `cmd.exe /c "command line"`. PowerShell is different from every shell I have ever used in that standard I/O redirection sets the shell as a middle man that decodes text, translates LF <-> CRLF newlines, and the re-encodes it. I never want this. By default the shell should directly connect pipe and file redirection without involving itself. CMD does it right.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as a PowerShell console. It's the same Windows console (conhost.exe) as all other console applications, including python.exe. Also,  Windows Python defaults to `locale.getpreferredencoding()` for non-console I/O, and UTF-8 for console I/O (internally transcoded to UTF-16 for the console's wide-character API). `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is the default encoding for script files and `str.encode`.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for all the info, when I tried to run the test.py program it also shows different output with and without  `>`, which is same as powershell. However, when I run `locale.getpreferredencoding()` in python, i get `cp1252`, which maybe the cause of the problem, thank you! I will check how to change it later.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I went to look at the outputs of your commands  on my machine and did some research but I don't quite understand them. Thanks for the info, I will try to learn more indepth when I am free.

Comment: @Kallzvx - the windows console allows multiple shells. one is CMD.exe, another is Powersehll.exe, and i presume there are others. so, if you see `powershell` as the current console prompt, use the powershell cmdlets to write to files, not the redirection operators. in your case, i suspect that `python_script.py | Out-File -Path c:\path\to\FileName.txt -Encoding ASCII` will do what you want.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It still prints `cp1252` and `utf-8` after executing `py test.py | Out-File -FilePath test.txt -Encoding ASCII`, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: We can override the default encoding for non-console `sys.std*` files via the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable. In newer versions we can override default to UTF-8 for all files via the command-line option `-Xutf8`.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, just run `cmd /c "py.exe -Xutf8 test.py > test.txt"`. For `-Encoding` to work, PowerShell has to first decode the program's stdout to UTF-16 and then re-encode, which can produce mojibake unless you've manually matched PowerShell's input text encoding to be the same as program's stdout encoding. If you have control over the program itself, such as with a Python script, it's best to exclude PowerShell from the equation.

Comment: @Kallzvx - it looks like you will need to take PoSh out of the loop. as eryksun pointed out, it adds an apparently unneeded layer to the whole problem - so remove it. [*grin*]

Comment: @eryksun `test.txt` shows `utf-8 utf-8` after running `py -Xutf8 test.py > test.txt`, so it  means I had the wrong `PYTHONIOENCODING` and it caused the problem?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for pointing it out, do you mean removing from the question tag and question description?

Comment: @Kallzvx - nope, leave the PoSh tag since it is a problem related to PoSh. try "fixing" the problem by NOT using the PoSh shell ... use the CMD shell instead.

Comment: `PYTHONIOENCODING` sets the encoding of Python's `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout`, and `sys.stderr`. OTOH, the `-Xutf8` option enables UTF-8 mode, which changes the default for *all files* to UTF-8.

Comment: In either case, in PowerShell, `> test.txt` does not run the command with its stdout set to a handle for the "test.txt" file. Instead it gets set to a pipe, with PowerShell on the other end. This is different from all other shells I've used. Encoded bytes written to stdout by the program (e.g. Python) get *transcoded* by PowerShell, including LF -> CRLF translation, and then written to the target file. Workarounds strictly within PowerShell are complicated. I'm saying to simply bypass this annoying behavior by running the command via `cmd.exe /c "command line"`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, @eryksun, after running `py test.py > test.txt` in `cmd.exe` or running `cmd.exe /c py test.py > test.txt` in powershell it still print `cp1252 utf-8` to the file...

Comment: @Kallzvx - it seems the most sensible solution is to use pure python to save your output. add a "save to file" option to your script with a parameter to control it. then call it with that parameter when you want file output instead of screen output. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes I can set `encoding=utf-8` when opening file in python, but it is pypassing the problem... thanks for helpping me out! For now it is not a big problem.

Comment: @Kallzvx - you are welcome ... glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Kallzvx, of course running `py test.py > test.txt` in any shell will report that `sys.stdout.encoding` is whatever the system ANSI codepage is, as returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. I already told you this. Override `sys.std` via `PYTHONIOENCODING`, or override the default to all files via UTF-8 mode, either via the `-X utf8` command-line option or [`PYTHONUTF8`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUTF8).

Answer (score 2):

**May I know why this happen**

Because the Python developers chose to do it like that.
See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout):

> On Windows, UTF-8 is used for the console device. Non-character devices such as disk files and pipes use the system locale encoding (i.e. the ANSI codepage).

**What should I do so that the default encoding is utf-8 when redirecting?**

Force the encoding.
I've added the following to my programs that were plagued by this problem:

```
if os.name == "nt":
    sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")
```

If you use `stderr`, you might want to reconfigure that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Windows. This is happening because the Windows 7 console does not understand UTF-8. So when you display standard output, it needs to encode as something Windows can display.

Luciano Ramalho's book [Fluent Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491946008) does a really good job explaining this.

Comment: It certainly *can* understand UTF-8, it just doesn't by default. You need to change the code page: `CHCP 65001`

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the console. That said, yes, even in Windows 10 the console is still buggy with UTF-8 (codepage 65001). For example, chcp.com sets both the input and output console codepages, and setting the input codepage to UTF-8 limits input to 7-bit ASCII. Non-ASCII characters are read as null bytes (`"\x00"`) in Windows 10, and in earlier versions of Windows, the whole read looks like EOF (i.e. a successful read of 0 bytes). UTF-8 output is also buggy in Windows 7 and earlier, but Windows 7 is almost at end of life.

Comment: @CodyGray emmm, changing code page to 65001 did not work, thanks for the suggestion